# Date not saving in right format vb6.0, SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I am trying to save this Date format in sql server 2005, all i get is 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
the code is

```
 txtRent_Date.Text = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Sql server stores datetime in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` format not in the format you are trying to save.

Comment: now i'm getting 6/27/1905 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I think you need to convert it to date before you pass it to database using `CDate();`

Comment: are you trying to format it for a textbox or send a date to SQL Server?

Comment: i'm trying to send the date to SQL Server :/

Comment: There is no SQL Server code in your example.

Comment: strsql = "INSERT INTO Rental_Copies(Rental_id,Copies_id,Rent_Date,Due_Date)Values(" & txtID.Text & "," & ListView1.ListItems(X + 1) & "," & txtRent_Date.Text & "," & txtDue_Date.Text & ")"

Comment: txtRent_Date.Text = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")  isn't this texbox getting the today's date ?

Comment: If the SQL Server column is a DATE type, you are sending text to the DB.  If the column is string you will have trouble using it in queries.  `txtRent_Date.Text` is a String (as are all `.Text`).

Comment: Don't concatenate SQL. Search this site for `parameterized queries` for the hundreds of discussions about why you shouldn't do so. In addition to the obvious danger of SQL  injection, your code is dependent on specific formats; parameterized queries allow the database drivers to deal with those sorts of issues, so you can simply assign a date type value to a date parameter without requiring a specific string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put apostrophes around your dates, like this:

```
strsql = "INSERT INTO Rental_Copies(Rental_id,Copies_id,Rent_Date,Due_Date)" & _
         "Values(" & txtID.Text & "," & ListView1.ListItems(X + 1) & ",'" & _
         txtRent_Date.Text & "','" & txtDue_Date.Text & "')"
```

Like others have said, you should be validating your data before using it and parameterizing your SQL to prevent SQL injection.