# Date not saving in database sql server and vb 6

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vb6

Hello I'm doing a project using SQL Server and VB 6

My project is on Library and most precisely on my RENTAL FORM. The date of the RENT AND DUE DATE is not being saved in my database

It is displaying in the Listview but saved as 1/1/1900 in my table.

I have changed the datatypes several times, it is still not being saved in my database.

Code :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   txtRent_Date.Text = Format(Now, "MM/ dd/ yyyy")
   txtDue_Date.Text = Format(Now, "MM/ dd/ yyyy")
End Sub


Private Sub Command1_Click()
 If Len(dcbBook.Text) = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Select a book First", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Alert"

 Else
   ' Save to Rental
   With Adodc1.Recordset
   .AddNew
.Fields("Customer_id") = dcbCustomer.BoundText
      .Update
      End With
    ' End Saving

txtID.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Rental_id").Value

' Save to Rental Copies
For X = 0 To ListView1.ListItems.Count - 1

         Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
         CN.CursorLocation = adUseClient
         CN.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Library;Data Source=SOUMEIYA-MSI\SQLEXPRESS"
         CN.Open
          strsql = "INSERT INTO Rental_Copies(Rental_id,Copies_id,Rent_Date,Due_Date)Values(" & txtID.Text & "," & ListView1.ListItems(X + 1) & "," & txtRent_Date.Text & "," & txtDue_Date.Text & ")"

          Set rs = CN.Execute(strsql)

         Next
      MsgBox "Book Rented successfully !", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Save"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is `Rent_Date` a Date column or text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482709/date-not-saving-in-right-format-vb6-0-sql-server-2005  I answered this question for another user a couple days ago.  Is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the date: `"," & txtRent_Date.Text & ","` in the SQL string so you attempt to insert the value `05/07/2014` which is interpreted as a *mathematical expression* with two divisions;

```
select 05/07/2014 == 0
```

Casting `0` to a date is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

Quote strings/dates in your statement or better use a parametrized query (put a ` in yourt textbox and see what happens).

Comment: can i have an example please

Answer (score 0):

Alan K is correct.  To fix the problem replace this portion of your insert statement...

```
& "," & txtRent_Date.Text & "," & txtDue_Date.Text & ")"
```

with...

```
& ",'" & txtRent_Date.Text & "','" & txtDue_Date.Text & "')"
```

Embedding sql in your application is a bad practice for many reasons.  You should convert your embedded insert statement to a stored procedure and set up parameters with the appropriate data types to pass the input values.